# pointer pointing to a memory block when gets free () matter what pointer is?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

Is a fast and simple question. I didn't find it in stackoverflow, so if it's already asked, I'm sorry.

I was doing a delete function for my BST (I'm learning) when I started to wonder how free work. free knows how many memory must be released and where it is, because the memory block contains that information. But, what pointer have to get the free?

for example in this code:

```
....
NODE* original,copy; //NODE is a struct.
NODE** copy2;
original=(NODE*)Malloc(sizeof(NODE));
copy=original;
copy2=&original;
free(copy)
....
```

I believe is something like this:

```
copy2---->original------>[memory block] <---------copy
```

my doubt is the next:

No matter what pointer is passed to free, the memory block gets released anyways?

so i can do:

```
free(original)
free(copy)
free(*copy2)
```

and is the same?

Sorry for any grammatical error, my English is kinda poor.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
copy=original;
```

is mere assignment of the pointer. You copied the address of the memory block from one variable to another like this:

```
   [.........memory block.........] <- You are freeing this NOT the pointer
   |
 copy
original
```

Now you free either - you will get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

```
free(original)
free(copy)
free(*copy2)
```

Yes, those all do exactly the same thing. And after you do any one of them, `original` and `copy` are invalid pointers. `copy2` is still a valid pointer to that points to `original`, but `*copy2` is not a valid pointer.

Unlike some languages, C does **not** keep track of how many pointers refer to a particular location in memory. So when you call `free` on any one of the pointers, the memory is released, and all of the pointers become invalid.

Answer (score 1):

`free()` expects the pointer used for `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()`

Instead of passing the same pointer to free() you are passing a copy of the same address using an intermediate pointer `copy`.

So it is similar to `free(original)`.

Where ever the pointer may be pointing there is a memory record maintained by the OS of the allocated space and that is used while freeing